# Find element that contains exact value and is of a certain class

Tags: jquery

I would like to find all `<td>`'s that have a `class of "rank"` and contain only the value 13,

*e.g value=1313 should not return any results.*

> So far I managed to find all td's that contain the number 13 and are
>   of type `<td>`. I havent managed to limit by class as well and by exact
>   value:

**So this is what I need:**

- Is of type `<td>`
- Is of class `"rank"`
- Contains exactly the number `"13"`.

This is what I got this far:

```
var highlight=$("td:contains("13")")
                .filter(function(){ return $(this).children().length === 0;})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var highlight=$("td.rank").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == "13";})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `td` element with class rank using selector `$("td.rank")`. You can then filter them based on content having 13 in them. Use:

```
var highlight=$("td.rank").filter(function(){ return $(this).html() == "13";})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3crter6c/)**